# error when trying to modify airflow.cfg in composer - Composer Backend timed out. Multiple errors occurred

Tags: google-cloud-platform, airflow, google-cloud-composer, airflow-webserver

I'm trying to configure sending emails through smtp, but I need to add a series of parameters in airflow.cfg, but whenever I make the insertions in the modifications tab of the airflow configuration, I always get the error below, I already have full permissions on composer environment, and there is no dag running at this time, just scheduled but not executed.

```
Composer Backend timed out. Multiple errors occurred. 
Got error "Could not start Composer Agent. DM deployments still pending.during CP-COMPOSER-AGENT-DEPLOYING [Could not start Composer Agent. DM deployments still pending.] .
Got error "Could not start Composer Agent. DM deployments still pending.
Http error status code: 488 
Http error message: BAD REQUEST 
Error messages: User not authorized to perform 
User not authorized to perform 
User not authorized to perform
User not authorized to perform 

Got error "Resource not found.
during CP-COMPOSER-AGENT-RUNNING [RPC Failed (Expected) : Pull Failure expected before subscription is created
```

I hope I can update airflow.cfg to be able to send emails

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)   (Because the text in that picture is too small to be read properly)    Also: Please update the title of this question to make it clear what the problem is

Comment: @Luuk, thanks for the tip, adjusted.

Comment: Could you follow this [document](https://hevodata.com/learn/airflow-emailoperator/) to update SMTP details in Airflow?

Comment: @Prajna Rai T , I already did, I tried several tutorials, until I contacted google cloud support and was informed that my composer version had this 'bug', so if I update to a version > 2.0.13, this problem will be solved.

Answer (score 0):

@LuizFelippe, As you have mentioned in the comment.

This issue will be resolved by updating to the composer version > 2.0.13.

Posting the answer as community wiki for the benefit of the community that might encounter this use case in the future.

Feel free to edit this answer for additional information.